# Slicing a list of strings and fill dictionary values

Tags: python

I have a list of strings and a dicionary that looks like this:

```
items_1 = [[1234,cat,air,here],[1234,cat2,air2,here2],[1234,cat3,air3,here3],[1235,dog1,rer1,type1],[1235,dog2,rer2,type2],[1235,dog3,rer3,type3]]
```

dictionary={'1234': [], '1235': []}

And I would like to have it this way:

```
items_1 = {1234:[[cat,air,here],[cat2,air2,here2],[cat3,air3,here3]],1235:[[dog1,rer1,type1],[dog2,rer2,type2],[dog3,rer3,type3]]
```

So far I have this code:

```
results_2=[]
for items_keyes in dictionary.keys():
    for index, list_id in enumerate(items_1):
        if items_keyes == results[index-1][0]:
           ID_to_fill[items_keyes[-1]].append(results)
```

But the output isn't like desired. Can someone help me please?

Comment: Your input data is unclear. Please add proper, runnable code.

Comment: What is `dictionary` in your code? Also `results[index-1][0]` will generate Index error. Better to provide sample of all the input of your program

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one-liner should provide the required output:

```
>>> {x: [v[1:] for v in items_1 if v[0] == x] for x in set(y[0] for y in items_1)}
{1234: [['cat', 'air', 'here'],
  ['cat2', 'air2', 'here2'],
  ['cat3', 'air3', 'here3']],
 1235: [['dog1', 'rer1', 'type1'],
  ['dog2', 'rer2', 'type2'],
  ['dog3', 'rer3', 'type3']]}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I would use [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict).

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)
for i in my_list:
    k = i[0]
    v = i[1:]
    d[k].append(v)
```